# Split seeds.rb into multiple sections?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, seed

I'd like to split my seeds.rb file into multiple sections for ease of maintenance; seed all the A's in a.rb, the B's in b.rb, etc.  The separate files are located in the db/ directory with seeds.rb.  Each file consists of a bunch of "A.create" or "B.create" calls and I want to call those files from seeds.rb.

I've tried:

```
include 'a'
include 'b'
```

and

```
load 'a.rb'
load 'b.rb'
```

in my seeds.rb but they don't seem to be processed when I call "rake db:seed".  This is probably more of a straight ruby question than a rails question but for completeness I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3 on a Mac.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `./db/seeds/my_module.rb`:

```
module MyModule
  puts "In my_module.rb"
  # add code here
end
```

In `./db/seeds.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path('../seeds/my_module', __FILE__) # the ../ just removes `seeds.rb` filename from the path which is given by __FILE__

p "In seeds.rb"
# add code here
```

Comment: I'm not sure if putting them in `db/migrate` is a great idea; migrations and seeds are different and should be treated as such. Instead, a `db/seed` directory would probably be better.

Comment: Yes, please don't put these in `db/migrate`, they belong in a separate folder such as `db/seed`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, of course.  Thank!  (And, I put them in a separate "seeds" directory)

Answer (score 4):

I would propose to create a new `db/seeds/` directory where you can place your various seeds file:

```
db/seeds/01_stuff_that_comes_for_first.rb
db/seeds/02_stuff_that_comes_for_second.rb
...
```

And then edit your `db/seeds.rb` file with:

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].sort.each { |seed| load seed }
```

So, you can load your seeds even in the order you prefer - that is often something requested.

---

This solution was originally proposed by nathanvda in this ["duplicated" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960630/1720344).